# Should I do a quest to acquire perm skills other than a Seal Clubber Skill?

Tags: kingdom-of-loathing

So I was looking through [Hardcore Skill Analysis](http://kol.coldfront.net/thekolwiki/index.php/Hardcore_Skill_Analysis)  on the KOL wiki and noticed Seal Clubbers don't have a recommended perm skill till tier 3. Being that Seal Clubber was my first pick starting the game, I feel like I shot myself in the foot to some extent. I wanted to go something other than a muscle class and it seems the highest recommended skills are for muscle classes.

I do know that there are skills you can acquire from quests and I'm wondering if I should go one of those as perm skills other then a seal clubber skill. Really looking for good non bias answers, I want to get the most out of my first play through as I want this character to stay my main.

Comment: note that you don't have to perm a skill on your ascension, instead you can bank up the karma and perm 2 skills on your next ascension.

Comment: Or you could just play for fun and do whatever seems like a fun idea. Ascension will speed up slowly. And your first ascension only gives 100 karma, you need 200 for a hardcore permed skill.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A little tip: don't go into hardcore unless you want to spend a month to ascend.
Since the Valhalla update you can now upgrade skills to HC if you have enough karma.

Start of with SC and learn all there is to a fast ascension. As for your pick, I would go with the **Musk of Moose** which really helps at the **Sonofa Beach** or the **Hide of the Walrus** since it's always good to have a passive skill.